# C# reads ConsoleColor from JSON How would code look like?

Tags: c#, json

Im trying to make a config that can change the color of the console message.
Here is the config

```
"ErrorColor": "Red",
```

here is before there was no config to change the color.

```
Console.ForegroundColor = color == ConsoleColor.Black ? ConsoleColor.Red : color;
```

here is what I tried to add it.

```
Console.ForegroundColor = color == ConsoleColor.Black ? ConsoleColor.(session.LogicSettings.ErrorColor) : color;
```

how would my code look like?

Comment: i was wondering how my code would look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse/TryParse is normally how you would get an enum value from a string, but isn't your json deserialization going to handle that? Anyway it would probably look like this

```
ConsoleColor color;
if (!Enum.TryParse(session.LogicSettings.ErrorColor, out color))
{
    // this is the fallback color in case an invalid value was entered.
    color = ConsoleColor.Red;
}

Console.ForegroundColor = color;
```

Comment: would i keep Console.ForegroundColor = color == ConsoleColor.Black ? ConsoleColor.(session.LogicSettings.ErrorColor) : color; or replace it?

Comment: @Mark No you wouldn't keep that. That's not even valid C#. This was more of a demonstration on how to use TryParse, not per se something for you to copy and paste.